# Draw tube from given array of 3d points

Tags: three.js

I want to draw some straight tube between given array of points using three.js. I tried using the [paint](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webvr_vive_paint.html#L240) example from threejs to draw tube between two points. So far i have done [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3foLr7sn/167/). But as you can see the tube get twisted after i apply the matrix.

Also, In three.js examples i have seen that they are using `TubeBufferGeomety` which takes various type of path like `CatmullRomCurve3, SplineCurve` as parameters. This generates curve type tube geometry like [this](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=spli#webgl_geometry_extrude_splines).

I want to draw straight **tube** between the points rather than any curve. Can anybody please suggest me what i am doing wrong in my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/3foLr7sn/167/) or is there any other way i can do it?

```js
// Simple three.js example

var mesh, renderer, scene, camera, controls;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  // renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // camera
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(20, 20, 20);

  // controls
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);

  // ambient
  scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x222222));

  // light
  var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
  light.position.set(20, 20, 0);
  scene.add(light);

  // axes
  scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(20));

  generateTubes();

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  //controls.update();

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

function generateTubes() {

  var tubeSideNumber = 8;
  var fixedIndexArray = [];
  var indices = [];
  var vertices = [];
  var colors = [];
  var tubeRadius = 1;

  generateFixedIndexedArray();

  var points = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    let posX = getRandomInt(0, i);
    let posY = getRandomInt(0, i);
    let posZ = getRandomInt(0, i);
    points.push(new THREE.Vector3(posX, posY, posZ));
  }
  createTubeGeometry(points, tubeRadius);

  var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  geometry.setIndex(new THREE.Uint8BufferAttribute(indices, 1));
  geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
  geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colors, 3));

  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  });
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  scene.add(mesh);



  function createTubeGeometry(positionArray, radius) {
    var shapes = getTubeShapes(radius);

    var len = positionArray.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
      insertVerticesForThisPoint(shapes, positionArray[i], positionArray[i + 1]);
    }

    insertVerticesForThisPoint(shapes, positionArray[len - 1], positionArray[len - 2]);

    var offset = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
      insertIndices(offset);
      offset += tubeSideNumber;
    }
  }

  function generateFixedIndexedArray() {
    for (var i = 0; i < tubeSideNumber; i++) {
      var a = i;
      var b = (i + 1) % tubeSideNumber;
      var c = tubeSideNumber + i;
      var d = tubeSideNumber + (i + 1) % tubeSideNumber;

      fixedIndexArray.push(c);
      fixedIndexArray.push(d);
      fixedIndexArray.push(b);

      fixedIndexArray.push(c);
      fixedIndexArray.push(b);
      fixedIndexArray.push(a);
    }
  }

  function getTubeShapes(radius) {
    var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
    var shapes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tubeSideNumber; i++) {
      var angle = (i / tubeSideNumber) * PI2;
      shapes.push(new THREE.Vector3(Math.sin(angle) * radius, Math.cos(angle) * radius, 0));
    }
    return shapes;
  }


  function getApplyMatrix(point1, point2, translatePoint) {
    var rotationMat = new THREE.Matrix4();
    rotationMat.lookAt(point1, point2, new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0));
    var translateMat = new THREE.Matrix4();
    translateMat = translateMat.makeTranslation(translatePoint.x, translatePoint.y, translatePoint.z);
    return rotationMat.multiply(translateMat);
  }

  function insertVerticesForThisPoint(shapes, thisPoint, pointToLookAt) {
    for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
      var vertex = shapes[i];

      vertex.applyMatrix4(getApplyMatrix(thisPoint, pointToLookAt, thisPoint));

      vertices.push(vertex.x);
      vertices.push(vertex.y);
      vertices.push(vertex.z);

      colors.push(Math.random());
      colors.push(Math.random());
      colors.push(Math.random());
    }
  }

  function insertIndices(offset) {
    for (var i = 0; i < fixedIndexArray.length; i++)
      indices.push(fixedIndexArray[i] + offset);
  }

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have a look at this [forum topic](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/profiledcontourgeometry/2330?u=prisoner849).

Comment: Please provide your code in your question. When (not if) your JSFiddle link becomes invalid, your link and your question lose important context. Stack Overflow provides [snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for running live code, just like JSFiddle.